# How to get response status code from jQuery.ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery-1.5

In the following code, all I am trying to do is to get the HTTP response code from a jQuery.ajax call. Then, if the code is 301 (Moved Permanently), display the 'Location' response header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>jQuery 301 Trial</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function get_resp_status(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      complete: function (jqxhr, txt_status) {
        console.log ("Complete: [ " + txt_status + " ] " + jqxhr);
        // if (response code is 301) {
        console.log ("Location: " + jqxhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));
        // }
      }
    });
  }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').mouseenter(
      function () {
        get_resp_status(this.href);
      },
      function () {
      }
    );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://ow.ly/4etPl">Test 301 redirect</a>
  <a href="http://cnn.com/not_found">Test 404 not found</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong? When I check the 'jqxhr' object in Firebug, I can't find the status code, nor the 'Location' response header. I set the breakpoint on last line of 'complete'.

Thanks much.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I know this is old, but I think I solved it (XHR.responseURL): http://stackoverflow.com/a/39416846/4946681

Answer (score 272):

I see the status field on the jqXhr object, here is a fiddle with it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/55HQq/3/

```
$.ajax({
    //...        
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    } 
});
```

Comment: It seems to be working in jsFiddle. Based on that and jQuery documentstion, xhr.status should do what I want. However, when I try the same in my original code (txt_status replaced with jqxhr.status), I keep getting jqxhr.status of 0. Here's a screenshot: http://twitpic.com/4alsqj

Comment: I believe the issue is you are not running against a web server but locally from the file system.  I think if you fired up a local web server this would work correctly, here are some articles on the subject: http://www.pearweb.com/javascript/XMLHttpRequest.html https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest "The key thing to note here is that the result status is being compared to 0 for success instead of 200.  This is because the file and ftp schemes do not use HTTP result codes."

Comment: this is great. Especially when I can have my backend send out status codes.

Comment: Note that if the response is a redirect status like 302 , this will give 200

Answer (score 59):

Came across this old thread searching for a similar solution myself and found the accepted answer to be using `.complete()` method of `jquery ajax`. I quote the notice on [jquery website](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here:

> The **jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete()** callbacks are **deprecated** as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use **jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always()** instead.

To know the `status code` of a ajax response, one can use the following code:

```
$.ajax( url [, settings ] )
.always(function (jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.status);
});
```

Works similarily for `.done()` and `.fail()`

Comment: This is returning "undefined"

Answer (score 57):

It is probably more idiomatic jQuery to use the statusCode property of the parameter object passed to the the $.ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    500: function(xhr) {
      if(window.console) console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
});
```

However, as [Livingston Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108296/livingston-samuel) said, it is not possible to catch 301 status codes in javascript.

Comment: while I'm trying to catch multiple status code like this, net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET accurse. any idea about fixing this?

Comment: it doesn't work with redirects

Answer (score 43):

When your XHR request returns a Redirect response (HTTP Status 301, 302, 303, 307), the `XMLHttpRequest` [automatically follows the redirected URL and returns the status code of that URL](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method).

You can get the non-redirecting status codes (200, 400, 500 etc) via the `status` property of the xhr object.

So you cannot get the redirected location from the response header of a `301`, `302`, `303` or `307` request.

You might have to change your server logic to respond in a way that you can handle the redirect, rather than letting the browser do it. An [example implementation](http://www.cupcakewithsprinkles.com/how-to-handle-http-redirects-with-jquery-and-django/).

Answer (score 35):

You can check your respone content, just console.log it and you will see whitch property have a status code. If you do not understand jsons, please refer to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts

It explains very basic knowledge that let you feel more comfortable with javascript.

You can do it with shorter version of ajax request, please see code above:

```
$.get("example.url.com", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).done(function() {
               // TO DO ON DONE
            }).fail(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                 //This shows status code eg. 403
                 console.log("error", data.status);
                 //This shows status message eg. Forbidden
                 console.log("STATUS: "+xhr);
            }).always(function() {
                 //TO-DO after fail/done request.
                 console.log("ended");
            });
```

Example console output:

```
error 403 
STATUS: Forbidden 
ended
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the full code of how to use done, fail and always, with full function parameters.

Answer (score 19):

NB: Using jQuery 3.4.1

```
$.ajax({
  url: URL,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log(textStatus + ": " + jqXHR.status);
    // do something with data
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(textStatus + ": " + jqXHR.status + " " + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

jqxhr is a json object:

> complete returns:
>  The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
>   categorizing the status of the request
>   ("success", "notmodified", "error",
>   "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

see:
[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

so you would do:

`jqxhr.status` to get the status