# how to get django's HttpResponse status code with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

My server "return HttpResponse()" when succuess, "return HttpResponse(status=400)" when failed.
My client has following jquery ajax function:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $.post("{% url 'addcomment' %}", {msg:$('#newcomment').val()}, function(data,status){
       if (status==200) {
          location.reload()
       } else {
          alert("Comment failed")
       }
   });
});
```

But the ajax code doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get response status code from jQuery.ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation clearly states, the success callback returns a `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR` argument

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-successdata--textStatus--jqXHR-dataType

If you want the response status get it from the third argument `jqXHR.status`