# Global variable inside Ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning the Ajax method with jQuery.  I've a simple code here.  It's to load data from a csv file by jQuery Ajax method, and put it into an array for further use.  But it seems the array lost outside of the Ajax function even I do make the array global in the first place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db=[];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loaddata.php',
        success: function(data){
            var arr = data.split('|');          
            for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
                var miniArr = arr[i].split(',');
                db.push(miniArr);
            }
            printTest();    //work here         
        }
    });
    printTest();    //not working and collapse here 
});

function printTest(){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += db;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" />
</body>
</html> `
```

My php file should be fine,

```
<?php
$database = file('database');
foreach($database as $item){
    if ($item===end($database))
        echo $item;
    else
        echo $item.'|';
}
```

?>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all - there's a syntax error when you put `printTest` in `$.ajax` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `printTest()` is where the `.ajax` parameters go, so there's a syntax error there. The reason the first call works is because it's inside the `success` callback, and since AJAX is **asynchronous** this is called when the call has completed.

If you put the `printTest()` call after the AJAX call, it will be called immediately after the AJAX call has started, not waiting until it completes, due to async.

Comment: @user2772441 -- Don't do that! There's no guarantee your AJAX call is going to finish in that time, so what if it doesn't? You should handle it in your `success` callback.

Comment: By the javascript httpRequest method I can check condition httpRequest.status == 200.  Are there any similar method to make sure the process complete before I go on with the other part of the program?

Comment: This thread should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax @user2772441

Answer (score -1):

You can't call your second printTest() here.

And for the record, try to use JSON to retrieve your datas, it's way much easier.