# Best way to obtain jqXHR status using $.post in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I found this topic ([How to get response status code from jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax)) in which it explain how to obtain the return the status, but I'm using `$.post` which makes it a little different.

I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
$('#update_marker').submit( function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.post($("#update_marker").attr("action"), $("#update_marker").serialize(), function(data) {
    if( $.trim(data).indexOf('<')==0 ) {
        new Messi( lang['dist_general_error'], {title: 'Ops...', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Fechar', val: 'X'}]});
    } else {
        var json = $.parseJSON( data );
        if( json.status=="success" ) {
            new Messi( json.msg );
        } else {
            new Messi( json.msg, {title: 'Ops..', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Fechar', val: 'X'}]});
        }
    }
});
return false;
});
});
```

So I thought I'd change the `$.post` call to something like

```
$.post($("#update_marker").attr("action"), $("#update_marker").serialize(), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

and it DOES work if I get `jqXHR.status` code = 200. But when the status = 500 I get nothing.

I'm trying to achieve this with minimal code changes as I have a lot of functions like this one, and I need to be able to capture the 500 code and treat in all of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please note that you can also listen to the Ajax events globally, http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery post only takes `success` as a parameter. The success handler is only called on successful ajax requests. If the request returns 500, the success handler, your callback, is never executed.

To attach an error handler, you can chain `.fail` after `.post` or switch to the broader [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

The first option means you modify your code by adding .fail like this

```
$(function() {
  $('#update_marker').submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($("#update_marker").attr("action"), $("#update_marker").serialize(), function(data) {
        if( $.trim(data).indexOf('<')==0 ) {
            new Messi( lang['dist_general_error'], {title: 'Ops...', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Fechar', val: 'X'}]});
        } else {
            var json = $.parseJSON( data );
            if( json.status=="success" ) {
                new Messi( json.msg );
            } else {
                new Messi( json.msg, {title: 'Ops..', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Fechar', val: 'X'}]});
            }
        }
    }).fail(function () { console.log("I errored!"); });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I would recommend getting accustomed to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) though, it is not difficult to get a hang of and it is much more extensible.

Comment: Yes, since `$.post()` returns a deferred object, `.error()` method is chainable here.

Comment: .error() is deprecated, use .fail() instead or .then(success,error)

Comment: Ok, I did and it worked. But there is something weird, when I simulate a return code 500 it works fine and calls `.fail()`. But when I simulate a PHP error like calling an invalid object, the return code is 200 and it ALSO calls `fail`. Why?