# Remote Script fail handling - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, src

In my code I am loading a script from a remote server. Here is what I have done:

```
var loadFlag = false;
var myWidgetScript = document.createElement("script");
myWidgetScript.type = "text/javascript";
myWidgetScript.charset = "utf-8";

myWidgetScript.src = document.location.protocol+ "//mytest.com/loader";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(myWidgetScript);
myWidgetScript.onreadystatechange=myWidgetScript.onload = myWidgetScript.onload = function() {
loadFlag = true;
if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
        //Do what you want
     }
};
if(!loadFlag){
    alert("Not loaded");
}
```

Now I want to generate an alert if script tag has failed to load from the URL. I am incase the URL has a typo or if the server **mytest.com** is down. But in my code it is generating alert even if the URL is correct and server is up...
What is wrong with my code?...
Can I have some other way to accomplish this..?

Comment: Is there any variable of External JS which you're going to use?

Comment: No, But the external JS is going to use my variables. These variables are going to be in `//Do what you want` area...

Answer (score 0):

Try this... May be it will help.

```
var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

        var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
        jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        jqTag.src = 'YOUR SCRIPT';

        headTag.appendChild(jqTag);

if (jqTag)
        {
        if (jqTag.readyState)
        {
            // For old versions of IE
            jqTag.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                alert('loaded');
            }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            // Other browsers
            jqTag.onload = function() {
            alert('loaded');
            };
        }
        }
```

Comment: The problem to address is not that script is loaded or not. The problem to address is that whether URL is accessible or not..!

Comment: How about this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax