# Check to see if .htm file exists always retuning true

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I want to check if a .htm file exists locally. I do:

```
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'blahblah',
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    console.log('xhr.status is ');
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('in the error');
                },
                async: false
            });
```

This works fine in chrome. But in Phonegap app on Android, this always goes to the success, whether the file exists or not and the status is always 200. Any ideas?

Comment: Your can check the response status ( i don't know how to retrieve it in jQuery ), just to give you an idea. If it equals 200 or 304, then file exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: @VLAS just edited question, checked and staus is 200 for files which definitely dont exist

Comment: did they exist some time earlier, if yes, then this can be result of caching. try to clear your cache.

Comment: nope never existed, im putting in nonsense for the url parameter and still 200 is returned!

Comment: Is your file a local one ? If yes, I've noticed an error in the Android `webivew` when you try to get it by Ajax.

Comment: yes its a local file, but it doesnt exist...

Comment: And the page that asks for the file is also local? You know, you can't access local files from JS loaded from remote server.