# How to define success handler in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have my jquery like,

```
 $('#SearchFor').button().click(function () {
        var SearchForValue = $("#NotAllotedStudentsList").val();
        var StudentInputTypeValue = $("#InputType").val();
        alert(StudentInputTypeValue);
        var options = {};
            options.type = "POST";
            options.url = "/Dashboard/NotAllotedStudentsList/";
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ model: { SearchFor: SearchForValue, StudentInputType: StudentInputTypeValue } });
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            $.ajax(options);
            success:handleData;
        });
        });
```

i dont know how to use this success(result,status,xhr) for my code, kindly tell me how to handle this successhandler.
i have my return type in controller like,

```
return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = tutorStudentsGridModelList, TotalRecordCount = studentListResponse.StudentList.Count() });
```

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344186/2276527)

Answer (score 1):

hai how about this one ?

```
   $('#SearchFor').button().click(function () {
        var SearchForValue = $("#NotAllotedStudentsList").val();
        var StudentInputTypeValue = $("#InputType").val();
        alert(StudentInputTypeValue);
        var options = {
                url : "/Dashboard/NotAllotedStudentsList/",
                type : "POST",
                data : JSON.stringify({ model: { SearchFor: SearchForValue, StudentInputType: StudentInputTypeValue } }),
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json"
            };

            $.ajax(options)
            .done( function(response, status, xhr) {
                 console.log(response);
            });

        });
    });
```

in my opinion its more readable recommend using function done() rather than success option

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying for ajax success add the success to the options like options.success=handleData , the handleData function will be called on ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

in Options add following line and make sure that handleData function should have parameters.
options.success= handleData; Remove success:handleData; from above code

Handle data function should be like:

```
function handleData(data,status,xhr){
//you can access data from data object like=> data.Result
}
```