# Sending login data to using ajax jquery, $ajax is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I want to send login data to api of website, if the statusCode returns 302 then I want to redirect the user to another webpage. But my jquery is not executing and giving me the error of **$ajax is not defined.** Below is my jquery code.

```
 $("#asd").click(function(){

                alert("sas");
               $ajax({
                            url:'url.com',
                            type: 'POST',

                            data: ({

                                 Username: $('#inputUserName').val(),
                                 password: $('#inputPassword').val(),
                                 returnURL: 'url.com',
                            }),
                            success : function(data, textStatus,jqXHR)
                            {
                                window.location.href="myvideo.html"
                            },
                            error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                            {
                                alert("Invalid username and password");
                            }

                     });

                }); 

});
```

Comment: use like this  `$.ajax({`  not  $ajax({

Comment: Can you tell me how can I get statusCode which is returned by the api? it will return 302 if username and pass is correct, otherwise not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its `$.ajax({})` not `$ajax`

```
 $.ajax({
         url:'url.com',
         type: 'POST',
         data: ({
             Username: $('#inputUserName').val(),
             password: $('#inputPassword').val(),
             returnURL: 'url.com',
          }),
          success : function(data, textStatus,jqXHR)
          {
             window.location.href="myvideo.html"
          },
          error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
          {
             alert("Invalid username and password");
          }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I get statusCode which is returned by the api? it will return 302 if username and pass is correct, otherwise not.

Comment: Check this link if you get any help from here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

It is not $ajax but $.ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can get more info on this method from link given above