# Get response code and parse to message via jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this structure:
HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="_ninja_forms_field_7" class="ninja-forms-field  popup-submit" id="ninja_forms_field_7" value="" rel="7">
```

JS:

```
$('#ninja_forms_field_7').click(function () {
    var name = $('#ninja_forms_field_6').val();
    var surname = $('#ninja_forms_field_6').val();
    var emailAddress = $('#ninja_forms_field_8').val();
    var eCommerceSiteUrl = $('#ninja_forms_field_9').val();




    var post_datas = emailAddress = +emailAddress+ & name = +name+ & surname = +surname+ & eCommerceSiteUrl = +eCommerceSiteUrl;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myserviceaddress',
        data: post_datas,
        success: function (answer) {
            console.log(answer);
        }
    });
});
```

It working good. But I want, If service response code 0, parse a text in page.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `error: function()` lines you see below beneath `success`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myserviceaddress',
    data: post_datas,
    success: function (answer) {
        console.log(answer);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#result_div").html("textStatus");
    }
});
```

Also, make sure you create a `<div id="result_div"></div>` so that the JQuery has a place to put the result in.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, error function is working but not I want this. I have many codes in service so generate text by response code. No one error code.

Comment: Have you looked at the top answer in this question? It seems to address the same issue you're having:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax