# How to handle aborted network requests?

Tags: php, html, firebug

Sorry, but I really don't know how to ask this in more appropriate terminology.

I want to show an image like this:

```
<img src="http://admin:1111@192.0.0.117:80/Streaming/picture" alt="Camera 1" style="width:256px;height:192px;">
```

It is shown properly when username, password, IP and port are correct.
But in case they are not correct Firebug shows me some error which I don't know how to handle.

If username or password is wrong, a `401 Unauthorized` error is shown in Firebug's *Net* panel. If IP or port is wrong, an `Aborted` error is shown.

If this error can be handled, how can I find out if the IP address or port is incorrect? If the IP is incorrect, it tries to load it for some seconds. If the port is incorrect, the `Aborted` error is shown immediately.

[image: 'Aborted' errors shown in Firebug's *Net* panel]

Comment: doing it using ajax? why don't your try the ajax response or status code?

Comment: I am begginer for php, ajax. Can you please give me an exapmle how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it using ajax, you can get the status code and take actions correspondingly.

```
$.ajax({
//...        
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
},
complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
} 
});
```

This might help you a lot.

[How to get response status code from jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax)

Comment: For clarification, the code shown above is not pure JavaScript functionality, it requires the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library.