# Rails returned status code to Ajax returning undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm sure I'm missing something very very simple here...

```
JQUERY CODE

  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url :  '/orders/create_or_update',
    dataType: 'json', 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(params)
  })
  .done(function(response){
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response)
  })

CONTROLLER CODE

  def create_or_update
    ...
    render json: {"name" => "test"}, status: 200
  end

OUTPUT OF CONSOLE.LOG

  undefined
  Object: {name: "test"}
```

Why is `response.status` in my jQuery not returning the `status: 200`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2:**

Actually, for the `.always` function, if the response is a success, the arguments are `(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`, but if it's a failure, it's `(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`.

In the docs, it's stated like this:

```
jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { })
```

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So, you'd need an `if/else` to display `jqXHR.status` in the always for all responses.

**EDIT:**

Your `response` is just the object that you're getting back from the `render` call. It doesn't have any notion of status. That's why it's undefined when you `.status` on it. I think the `.always` is necessary b/c it will cover both `.done` and `.fail` responses from the controller. If you're only ever going to get the `.done` method, and you want that to take care of it, you can do this (note the extra `textStatus` argument):

```
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url :  '/orders/create_or_update',
    dataType: 'json', 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(params)
  })
  .done(function(response, textStatus, xhr){
    console.log(xhr.status)
    console.log(response)
  })
```

So, you should be able to do this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url :  '/orders/create_or_update',
    dataType: 'json', 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(params)
  })
  .done(function(response){
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response)
  }).always(function(a, textStatus, b){
    console.log(a.status); // One of these two will be `undefined`
    console.log(b.status);
  })
```

And that will print the status to the log.

Comment: can you explain this to me a bit more? is the `always` necessary? i thought from reading the logs the `response` should be enough, that's why i'm confused as to why it's NOT working