# Regex to match response as 200 OK

Tags: javascript, regex

For a REST call I am getting response back. I am getting response as:

*call_name* *response_code* OK

Now I want to give an if condition if my response code is either 200 or 201.
So what is the regex pattern that I should use?

**Example:**

```
response.body = getOtp 200 OK

if(response.body.match()) {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Comment: should it be `if {} else {}` condition for `200` and `201` code?

Comment: How are you making your request. You should be able to access the status code directly without using regex. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status

Answer (score 4):

You can use character set to match either 200 or 201 codes:

```js
var response = {body:"getOtp 200 OK"};

if(response.body.match(/20[01] OK/)){
    console.log("Matching");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(response.body.match(/20[01]/) && reponse.body.match(/\bOK\b/)){
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Hope it helps. Didn't get to test it, but It should work just fine.

Comment: I already posted this before I know he wanted to match 201 as well. I already edited it

Answer (score 0):

```
if(response.body.match(/200|201/){
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as OP. However I ran into a problem:

> "___.match is not a function"

Thought I'd share what solved it for me:

```js
if (String(response.status).match(/20[01]/)) {
    // do stuff
}
```