# What is textStatus when an HTTP error is received from an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In jQuery, when an AJAX request fails due to an HTTP error (e.g., 500 Internal Server Error) what is the value of the *textStatus* argument to the error handler? E.g.,

```
$.ajax(...).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus); // What is this when an HTTP error occurs?
});
```

The jQuery documentation for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) simply lists the possible values, but there is no clear explanation as to when they occur. Particularly, jQuery mentions:

> When an HTTP error occurs, `errorThrown` receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."

But it does not say what the value of *textStatus* will be.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If there was an `httperror` status, I'd agree.

Comment: If you mean that you want to get the HTTP status code from the response, you can do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't particularly care about the exact HTTP status code, just whether the response is specifically an HTTP response error (e.g., 4xx or 5xx) as oppose to some other potential error (e.g., transport, timeout, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive an HTTP error response (e.g., 500 Internal Server Error), the value of the *textStatus* argument will be `"error"`. This was determined through testing.