# Check what response XHR returns Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, request-headers

I'm trying to make a check where i can redirect the user to a other page if the XHR request returns a 403 error. My current XHR request is set like this

```
beforeSend:  function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
},
```

This is inside a AJAX call. How could i redirect the user if the XHR returns a 403? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get response status code from jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax)

Comment: why don't you use `fail` method ?