# How do I get the jqXHR object when I call JQuery ajax with await?

Tags: jquery, ajax, async-await

I make a jquery ajax call and get the async result after it is finished with await:

```
async () => {
  const result = await $.ajax (url);
  console.log (result);
}
```

But in result I have only the content of the response, I want to get the headers and status code and so on from thejqXHR object. How do I get this?

To answer Rituls question, I want to write something like:

```
const result = await $.ajax(url);
const content = result[0];
const jqxhr = result[1];
console.log ('content:', content, 'status:', jqxhr.status);
```

EDIT:

I tried the following workaround and get a strange behaviour (Code is typescript):

```
const result = await ajax (gondorHeaderUrl);
console.log ('ajax result:', result);
console.log ('typeof ajax result:', typeof result);

function ajax (url: string, settings?: JQuery.AjaxSettings): Promise<JQuery.jqXHR> {
  return new Promise (((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax (url, settings)
      .then ((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
          console.log ( 'jqXHR:', jqXHR);
          console.log ( 'typeof jqXHR:', typeof jqXHR);
          resolve (jqXHR);
        },
        (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => reject (jqXHR)
      );
  }));
}
```

Console:

```
jqXHR: Object { readyState: 4...................
typeof jqXHR: object
ajax result: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...............
typeof ajax result: string
```

Why is result different from jqxhr? When I wrap it into an object it works:

```
resolve ({j:jqxhr});
```

Comment: I think you may have to use the old `.then()` syntax to get more than one value.

Comment: what exactly  you are looking for ..can you please collaborate please.,

Comment: `$.ajax (url).always(function (jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.status);
});` to get status. For more in detail go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax)

Comment: If anyone is still looking for the answer, then answer is simple; *Delay the await call*.
You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231409/15066006 for more details.
Basically store the `jqXHR` object from `$.ajax` call, await the object to get response, and once the await is completed, the `jqXHR` object would contain all the details you need